# Hide scrollbar in pre if not needed

Tags: html, css

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow) says that a horizontal scrollbar is supposed to be always shown if overflow-x: scroll is set.

On my website I often post code in a `<pre>`-Block. As this has no predefined width, but the surrounding div does have a maximum (defined as percentage), it seems that I can not figure out how to achieve the following:
In case a code block is not too wide, hide the horizontal scrollbar.
If it exceeds the width, show a scrollbar. 
Any hints? I think I have tried most of the combinations of overflow-x and -y, but none seem to do what I want.

Comment: Uh, you’re already using `overflow: auto` on your site and it works. Why the question?

Comment: Ok, maybe it is a problem with my browser: But both on FF 3.0 and FF 3.5 I see this.

Comment: No one else is seeing the issue. Maybe you're logged in and as such get a different set of style sheets?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use:

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

`auto` tells the browser to only show a scrollbar if the content exceeds the width of the box.

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect, at least with FF3.5. Please look at my website to see that this does not work (for some reason).

Comment: Your website works for me, and I *am* using Firefox 3.5 so the problem must be elsewhere. Furthermore, I am certain that this *is* correct. Have you tried re-installing your browser?

Comment: Did you really check on my website? It works perfectly as long as there is no border-bottom defined. If I show a bottom border for the pre element, it gives me the scroll bar. Usually, your tip would be correct

Comment: The suggested solution still shows the scrollbar if not needed. Even worse it also activates the vertical scrollbar.

I guess there´s currently no solution to conditionally show/hide the scrollbar depending on the content exceeding the container dimensions or not.

Comment: @mwld No, that’s not the case. Maybe you are using a very (!) outdated browser – but as I remember, even IE6 supported this. More likely the cause is something else entirely. Try producing a minimal test case that displays the problem, and debug it.