# Using overflow:scroll, hide unused scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

I have a div with `overflow:scroll`.

In Chrome, if a line of text is too long, a scrollbar will appear. If the line is not too long, no scrollbar will appear. That is the desired behavior.

In Firefox, however, scrollbars appear regardless of the length of the div's content. If the line is too short, the scrollbars are simply unusable. How do I fix this, so that the div can scroll only if its contents warrant it?

Comment: post your code then we can help you.

Comment: I present to you: my code: http://jsfiddle.net/F364X/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Take a look here:
[Hide scrollbar in pre if not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675414/hide-scrollbar-in-pre-if-not-needed)